# Azure Functions with blob storage. How to create a BlobTrigger to a sub-folder?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

I need to react to a blob that's added into a sub-folder. I know that blob storage doesn't recognize the folders, they are just virtual, but I still can't figure out how to create a blob trigger if files are added to sub-folders.

Example:

Excerpt from `function.json`:

`{
  "name": "myblob",
  "type": "blobTrigger",
  "direction": "in",
  "path": "rootContainer/{name}"
}`

OK, a function is triggered and I receive the blob

Excerpt from `function.json`:

`{
  "name": "subfolder/myblob",
  "type": "blobTrigger",
  "direction": "in",
  "path": "rootContainer/{name}"
}`

or

`{
  "name": "myblob",
  "type": "blobTrigger",
  "direction": "in",
  "path": "rootContainer/subfolder/{name}"
}`

NOT OK, a function isn't triggered

There are not many questions regarding this problem and they still don't provide a normal answer. Can't find any info in documentation either.

Thanks!

Comment: The second configuration should work. Make sure you upload to the right folder and your subfolder name is right.

Comment: Per my test, if we use `"path": "rootContainer/subfolder/{name}"`, it works fine, this is my [result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7wsi.png), I find there is no `connection` in your `function.json`, may it caused by this? But you said it works with `rootContainer/{name}`, it is strange, I recommend you to change a storage account or explorer to try again.

Comment: Yes, I omitted `connection` for brevity. I noticed that it's fired when a root is `rootContainer`, and blob which comes has the following name `subfolder/{name}`. It isn't fired for path being `rootContainer/subfolder`.

Comment: @Semuserable Did you run this trigger locally or on portal, which is your runtime version, v1 or v2?

Comment: I try to run it on a portal, runtime version is `~1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortly speaking, `"path": "rootcontainer/subfolder/{name}"` should work.

Logs panel on function portal may not show logs in time, you can go to `https://{functionappname}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`, then navigate to `D:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\function\yourblobtriggername` to see log files.

If you use blob name in your function code, `path` should include `{name}`, otherwise function won't run due to runtime exception.

If you set `path` as a container like `mycontainer` or `mycontainer/{name}`, all files written to this container(including those uploaded to virtual subfolder) will trigger the function. 
As you have mentioned:

> it's fired when a root is `rootcontainer`, and blob which comes has the following name `subfolder/{name}`

If you set it as a subfolder like `mycontainer/subfolder/{name}`, only files written to this subfolder will trigger the function.

If set to `mycontainer/subfolder`, not triggered as you have found.

Feel free to ask if you have further questions.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's working, but it runs very strangely. Sometimes its instantaneous and other times it takes up to 5 minutes. Can find any correlation, unfortunately.

Comment: @Semuserable You probably met [cold start in consumption plan](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2018/02/07/understanding-serverless-cold-start/), and [some reliable research](https://mikhail.io/2018/04/azure-functions-cold-starts-in-numbers/) for you to refer.

Comment: Thank you for the links! I'll definitely research this behavior in depth.