# Azure function BlobTrigger not firing on new file in new subfolder

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

My Azure function becomes unresponsive (new Blob trigger doesn't trigger) overnight, and starts working again when I click on that job in the Azure portal UI.

**update 9th August 11:17** - it is when $logs creates a new subfolder every hour, the BlobTrigger doesn't get triggered by these new files
[image]

> when a new folder is created the BlobTrigger isn't triggered when new
>   files are created in that folder.

**end update**

```
public static class Function2
{
    [FunctionName("Function2")]
    public static void Run([BlobTrigger("$logs/{name}", Connection = "ddavemstorage")]
    Stream blobStream, string name, TraceWriter log, ExecutionContext context)
```

I can verify the $logs files are being written regularly (using Azure Storage Explorer) but don't trigger the BlobTrigger overnight.

[image]

Screenshot taken at 1016. 30minutes ago I looked at the portal Azure Function UI. It then processed the log file from 0600UTC (actually 0700 my time). And it processed all the others which it had missed.

- Plan: Consumption: 0 Small
- Runtime: 1.0.11913.0 (.NET full)

It may be possible this is something to do with the $logs folder. This couldn't be monitored a few years ago. https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/715

[image]

$logs folder is being written to as expected.

Comment: Not really answering the question, but there are some hints out there that Blob Triggers should be treated as not 100% reliable and that the newer Events model triggering via Event Grid may give better reliability than a Blog Trigger directly on a Function:

see: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#trigger---polling
and:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview

Comment: I would also suggest trying a Standard App Service Plan rather than a Consumption model might provide a better reliability (but will of course cost more).

Answer (score 0):

In storage, the subfolders are virtual, and not similar to an actual file system. A workaround and possible solution for your issue is to include the full path by providing the subfolder name such as: `"path": "rootcontainer/subfolder/{name}"` in function.json.

There is a similar thread posted recently talking about the same issue as well, you can see it [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50976715/azure-functions-with-blob-storage-how-to-create-a-blobtrigger-to-a-sub-folder) for more info.

Comment: Thanks @Adam - as the $logs folder created lots of virtual subfolders depending on data and time, this could work but I've found another workaround which looks a bit easier (described in separate answer).. unless I've missed something

Answer (score 0):

By creating a second function of type TimerTrigger every 5 minutes I found that the first BlobTrigger function now picks up the files as expected.

```
public static class TestTimer
{
    [FunctionName("TestTimer")]
    // runs every 5 minutes
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }
}
```